# Getting "new build" status from land registry SPARQL

Tags: sparql

Sorry but I just can't get my head around SPARQL!  Could someone help me out with writing a query to get whether or not a property was a new build from the [land registry API](http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/common?_page=0#N10070) please?

Here is the query I've got so far:

```
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX lrppi: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ppi/>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX lrcommon: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/common/>

SELECT ?paon ?saon ?street ?town ?county ?postcode ?propertytype ?amount ?date
    WHERE {
        ?transx lrppi:pricePaid ?amount .
        ?transx lrppi:transactionDate ?date .
        ?transx lrppi:propertyAddress ?addr .
        ?transx lrppi:propertyType ?propertytype .
        ?addr lrcommon:postcode "AB1 1AB" ^^xsd:string .
        ?addr lrcommon:postcode ?postcode .
        OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:county ?county .}
        OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:paon ?paon .}
        OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:saon ?saon .}
        OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:street ?street .}
        OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:town ?town .}
    } ORDER BY ?amount
```

Comment: I wish people would explain their downvotes please...??! I'm not a mind reader and I can't improve my question without knowing why you down-voted!

Comment: @Anupheas The down vote arrow specifically says in the tool tip "This question does not show any research effort", your question is just a cut and paste of an example query from the Land Registry site that appears to have no relation to the actual query you want to run which is likely why you were down voted.  There are plenty of good SPARQL tutorials out there (e.g. [SPARQL by Example](https://www.cambridgesemantics.com/en_GB/semantic-university/sparql-by-example)) which would help you learn SPARQL

Comment: I'm not sure that the SPARQL endpoint even includes that data you want, http://landregistry.data.gov.uk describes the data that is available and none of it appears to include whether a property is new build

Comment: Related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982615/how-to-access-the-land-registry-dwelling-type-from-a-sparql-query?rq=1

Comment: @RobV Sorry but I saw that related question any my query already encompasses the property type/dwelling type.  Although that is "related" it does not solve the problem I have.

Comment: @RobV I appreciate you clarifying the situation with the down-vote.

Comment: @RobV I'll admit, I was a little lazy, but in my defense, I have actually tried to learn SPARQL (I've spent a few hours) and I'm really stumped!  Maybe I'm getting old but I work using t-sql, c#, mvc, typescript, javascript everyday and this SPARQL is nothing like anything I've ever seen.  Also, once I get this new build flag sorted, it is likely I'll never have to use it again and I thought if someone knew the answer quickly then I could get the job done without having to fully learn and understand SPARQL.  So yes, hands up, I'm being a bit lazy and I apologise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all let's rewrite your query so it's much easier to read:

```
PREFIX lrppi: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ppi/>
PREFIX lrcommon: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/common/>

SELECT ?paon ?saon ?street ?town ?county ?postcode ?propertytype ?amount ?date
  WHERE {
    ?transx lrppi:pricePaid ?amount ;
            lrppi:transactionDate ?date ;
            lrppi:propertyAddress ?addr ;
            lrppi:propertyType ?propertytype .
    ?addr lrcommon:postcode "AB1 1AB" ;
          lrcommon:postcode ?postcode .
    OPTIONAL {
        ?addr lrcommon:county ?county ;
              lrcommon:paon ?paon ;
              lrcommon:saon ?saon ;
              lrcommon:street ?street ;
              lrcommon:town ?town .
    }
  } ORDER BY ?amount
```

You can use a `;` to still use the subject and ask for a new object. While `.` ends your query. Further you can also combine `OPTIONAL` and you don't need `^^xsd:string` for a string.

If you don't get any results something in your query is wrong, probably the postcode. Start by removing parts of the query to see if you get any results and than build it up again. That's the easiest way to do SPARQL in my opinion. If you need more information, check out the [EUCLID-project webinar 2](http://www.euclid-project.eu/resources/webinars-recordings). That provides an introduction to SPARQL and will make it much easier to understand.

I couldn't find the SPARQL endpoint, so that's why I couldn't test your query unfortunately... Maybe you can provide a SPARQL endpoint for more help?

---

EDIT: After finding the SPARQL endpoint thanks to @RobV, I tested out my query. After all `^^xsd:string` was required for the land registry SPARQL endpoint, but that's no biggie, we didn't even need it. Also the set postcode didn't exist in the dataset so that's why you wouldn't get any results. Anyway this is the query to get all the new build houses for all postcodes:

```
PREFIX lrppi: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ppi/>
PREFIX lrcommon: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/common/>

SELECT ?paon ?saon ?street ?town ?county ?postcode ?propertytype ?amount ?date
  WHERE {
    ?transx lrppi:pricePaid ?amount ;
            lrppi:transactionDate ?date ;
            lrppi:propertyAddress ?addr ;
            lrppi:propertyType ?propertytype ;
            lrppi:newBuild true .
    OPTIONAL {
        ?addr lrcommon:county ?county ;
              lrcommon:postcode ?postcode ;
              lrcommon:paon ?paon ;
              lrcommon:saon ?saon ;
              lrcommon:street ?street ;
              lrcommon:town ?town .
    }
  } LIMIT 100
```

I limited it to 100 rows because of the performance of the land registry SPARQL endpoint. You could also make some elements mandatory instead of optional for a full resultset or do a `SELECT DISTINCT` to filter out all the duplicates. But that's just nitpicking.

Comment: The endpoint is at http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/landregistry/sparql/sparql.html, it's linked from the bottom of the OPs linked page

Comment: My apologies but I used AB1 1AB as a postcode example, I knew it was not real but I couldn't think of a way to say "use your postcode here" that didn't look like it should be part of the query.

Comment: You could also `SELECT DISTINCT ?postcode WHERE {?s lrcommon:postcode ?postcode}` to get all unique postcodes in the dataset.