# combining information from land registry through SPARQL

Tags: sparql

I am looking to obtain information on sales transactions for particular postcodes using the land registry SPARQL query tool. However, I also wish to acquire information regarding the local authority index for each sale transaction, from the same query.

I have two separate queries which I know work. The first query obtains house price index information for each postcode.  This gives the local authority index, to which the postcodes belongs too, on a monthly basis.  The code for this is shown here: [HM Land Registry SPARQL postcode query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56996891/hm-land-registry-sparql-postcode-query)   (This has been altered ever so slightly by changing the code as suggested by members in response to my first query, through using: (?region (owl:sameAs|rdfs:seeAlso) ?ordnanceSurveyRegion))

The second query produces transactions for each postcode.  The code for this, is as shown below.

I wish to combine the queries, so that I can obtain the transaction information with the attached monthly local authority index (to whom the postcodes belong to), for when the transaction took place.

I've tried adding/adjusting various code to what I've pasted below.  Nothing however, seems to work. I either get no data output or a variety of different errors.

I am aware that this is a more general question, but thought it was worth asking whether what i'm trying to do, is possible?

Any information would be much appreciated,
Many thanks

```
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
prefix sr: <http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/ontology/spatialrelations/>
prefix pc: <http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/ontology/postcode/>
prefix ukhpi: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ukhpi/>
prefix lrppi: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ppi/>
prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
prefix lrcommon: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/common/>

# Returns the Price Paid data from the default graph for each transaction record having
# an address with the given postcode.
# The postcode to query is set using SPARQL 1.1's 'values' clause

    SELECT  ?street ?town ?county ?postcode ?amount ?date ?category ?estateType ?propertyType
    WHERE
    {
      VALUES ?postcode 
          {
          # Insert postcodes here (two example postcodes below)
          "NP20 5AW"
          "SW1W 0NY"
          "GL2 8LT"
          "BD24 9BX"
          "LE67 4AF"
          "LE67 4AH"
          "LE67 4QP"
          "LE67 4AG"
    }
  ?addr lrcommon:postcode ?postcode.

  ?transx lrppi:propertyAddress ?addr ;
          lrppi:pricePaid ?amount ;
          lrppi:transactionDate ?date ;
          lrppi:estateType ?estateType ;
          lrppi:propertyType ?propertyType; 
          lrppi:transactionCategory/skos:prefLabel ?category.


  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:county ?county}    
  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:street ?street}
  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:town ?town}

}
ORDER BY ?amount
```

Comment: We don't have enough information about your data to provide advice. You say you want "the ukhpi for the local authority (for each transaction)." OK; is there a predicate in your dataset that connects each "transaction" to its "local authority"? and a predicate in your dataset that connects each "local authority" to its "ukhpi"? If these predicates exist, but not in your dataset, then you'll either need to load more data, or use a [Federated SPARQL (a/k/a SPARQL-FED) query](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-federated-query/).

Comment: Thanks for your response.   One of the queries i mentioned, does give each  postcode's ukhpi specifically for the local authority area that the postcode is located in (on a monthly basis).  So thats not an issue. The other query gives transactions for the postcodes.  So what I am trying to do is to link these two seperate pieces of information into one query. However, I havent at the moment got a predicate that connects each transaction to its local authority, so that is useful to know.  Apologies if i'm coming across as a bit slow, i'm new to coding, so appreciate your help.

Comment: Given that each `transaction` has a `postcode`, and each `postcode` has a `local_authority`, it is definitely possible to show the `local_authority` for each `transaction`. At minimum, we'd need to see your two queries, and to know whether they are running on the same endpoint, to advise how to blend them.

Comment: So the query for transaction information is shown in the code, which I have posted  above.  The  query for the index information is the code I pasted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56996891/hm-land-registry-sparql-postcode-query  (This has been altered ever so slightly by changing the code as suggested by members in response to my first query, through using:  (?region (owl:sameAs|rdfs:seeAlso) ?ordnanceSurveyRegion) ).  Thanks

Comment: I suggest you edit this question to include the extra details now seen in the comments, as that will help future readers understand the whole picture (and know whether it's relevant to them) more quickly. That will also make it easier for us to provide suggestions for this current question.